# How to get PHP Function value?

Tags: php, function, find

When using a funciton for example, "get_photo_id" and I use the number 6 inside.

EXAMPLE:

```
<?php get_photo_id("6"); ?>
```

i want the function get_photo_id to get the value inside (which is 6 in this case). To be able to find the number inside and assign a variable to it.

Something like this:

```
function get_photo_id() {

<!--something to find the value used and assign it as $valueused -->

get_cat_id('$valueused')
echo 'cat_id'
}
```

I hope you get what i mean... im kind of new in php!

Comment: Can you please clarify your question. What do you mean with "find the number inside"? Find it in an array, file on disk, database? The question is a bit unclear and it is hard to see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: There are multiple things you need to learn first. Have a look at the PHP manual on [functions](http://php.net/functions) and [variables](http://php.net/variables). Or peek at some tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

Function arguments are passed as follows:

```
function foo($argument1, $arg2)
{
    var_dump($argument1, $arg2, func_get_args());
}

foo("test", 12);
```

results in

```
string(4) "test"
int(12)
array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "test" [1]=> int(12) }
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This was the first answer and is entirely correct.

Comment: besides, he knows where to put curly braces ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean function parameters?

```
function foo($arg)
{
    echo $arg;
}
```

When you call `foo("6")` it will echo `6`. However, if you want to work with numbers, its better to call `foo(6)` with a number, instead of a string containing a number.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about your question, but this might be the answer from what i understand

```
function get_photo_id($value) {

    <!--something to find the value used and assign it as $valueused -->

    get_cat_id($value);
    echo 'cat_id'
}
```